# Detecting arrow keys via the standard input stream on LINUX

Tags: c++, linux, arrow-keys

I'm trying to implement a command line for my tool and I want to allow the user to get the previous command easily by pressing the up/down arrow keys like that in a terminal.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    std::vector<std::string> stack;
    std::string buffer;
    std::string str;

    while(1){
        buffer.clear();
        str.clear();
        std::cout<<"cmd>";
        while(std::cin.peek() != '\n'){
            std::cin >> buffer;
            if(!str.empty()){
                str += ' ';
            }
            str += buffer;
        }

        if(str == "quit"){
            break;
        }
        else{
            stack.push_back(str);
        }
        std::cout<<"Stack: ";
        for(int i = 0;i < stack.size();i++){
            std::cout<<stack[i]<<"->";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So far it looks something like this, but I don't know how to detect the arrow keys. I know that there is no standard C++ way for doing this, and I am OK with a LINUX-only solution.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Strong suggestion: consider using [ncurses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/)

Comment: It can't really be done in a nice way using standard C++ functionality and the standard `std::cin` stream. Depending on platform you might want to look at things such as [the GNU readline library](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html), or [the Windows console functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use this: [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) 
Google for some easy examples how to detect the arrows